# How to Stretch Gridview width inside a Div or a Panel in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

[image]

Based on the image above. I have a gridview that I like to be stretched, fixed containing the whole div that it is paneled inside. The problem is when it automatically adjust based on the contents width.

The gridview is incorporated with javascript commands that make the header fixed. I can actually make the desired output by putting a **width=100%** property in the gridview. However since it has jquery command injectedl, when I include the width property it is resulting to this

[image]

here are the codes

```
     <div class="GridviewPanelBody">


      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Font-Size="Smaller" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<emptydatarowstyle backcolor="white" forecolor="black"/>             
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Location" DataField="locationd" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Retail Partner" DataField="name"   />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FL Area" DataField="sqm"   />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Previous Month" DataField="PreviousMonth" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}"  />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Current Month" DataField="CurrentMonth" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Year Month" DataField="LastYearMonth" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sales/SQM" DataField="SALES/SQM"  DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}"/>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Inc/Dec%" DataField="INC/DEC%"  DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;}" />

         </Columns>

       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="25px"/>
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
  </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

part of the css

```
 .GridviewPanelBody
{
             background-color: #FaFaFa;

             margin-left: auto;

             margin-right: auto;

             overflow: auto;

             height: auto;   

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put width attribut for your gridview object:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPersons" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100px">
```

And, Set AutoSizeMode property of the column to AllCells.

Comment: I am actually putting a width="100%" property,but as a result it is getting a one column output for gridview (kindly see 2nd image in the question) i believe it is because of the jquery plugin.